# Got a TypeError after update and need to adapt found solution

Tags: javascript

I've recently updated my WP and I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: switchEditors.switchto is not a function
```

I've found this:

```
This is due to changes to the core in Wordpress 4.3+. You need replace onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);" to data-wp-editor-id="'+current_id+'"
```

Here is my code:

```
switchEditors.switchto( document.getElementById("ssquiz_question-tmce") );
if ( state == 'add') {...}
```

I tried to adapt the line but can't get it to work. Any help will be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should update your plugin, this has been fixed

Comment: the plugin has not been updated for the last 6 years and I have been adding or changing  functionalities. So I have to do it.

Comment: @ominem Did you find any solution?